# What is the proper way to make an api call via springs `WebClient`, but ignore the result?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

What is the proper way to make an api call via springs `WebClient`, but ignore the result? The `ClientResponse` object specifically calls out that I have to do something with the result...

[Docs:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html)

> NOTE: When given access to a ClientResponse, through the WebClient exchange() method, you must always use one of the body or toEntity methods to ensure resources are released and avoid potential issues with HTTP connection pooling. You can use bodyToMono(Void.class) if no response content is expected. However keep in mind that if the response does have content, the connection will be closed and will not be placed back in the pool.

Can I make a WebClient call and ignore the results? or is there a generic catch all *"body or toEntity method"* that I can use and then ignore?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Prior to Spring Framework 5.2, using the [`WebClient#exchange()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchange--) method and dealing directly with the `Mono<ClientResponse>` could be quite complex or lead to potential memory leaks.

As of Spring Framework 5.2, this has been made much easier for developers and the `exchange()` method has been deprecated.

```java
Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> response = webClient.put()
     .uri("https://example.org/book/123")
     .retrieve()
     .toBodilessEntity();
```

Spring will read the response body (if present) and release the data buffers, and then return the connection to the pool. It's making sure that there's no memory leak, including when additional Reactor operators are used.

Comment: Just to get a better understanding: in the last example, does it read any data before releasing the connection? As I understood, in your examples we read the response body (to have clear state and be able to reuse connection) but ignore it?

Comment: in the last example, we're indeed reading the response body and releasing buffers as they come. We'll release the connection properly to the pool.

Comment: Hi @BrianClozel, thanks a lot for this helpful response. The problem with the Javadoc is that "to ensure resources are released and avoid potential issues with HTTP connection pooling" gives the impression that you will have e.g. memory leaks if you don't consume the response, or if you use bodyToMono(Void.class) and the server sends a body. Actually, your first TL;DR clarifies that at worst you will have a performance hit, which is a far lesser problem (if any)! This should be rectified by working your first "TL;DR" into the Javadoc quoted by the OP.

Comment: Hopefully spring framework makes the last option into a convenience method.

Comment: @raven I've updated the answer for Spring Framework 5.2, which is now the minimum version supported. At this time, upgrading to Spring Framework 5.3 is strongly advised.

Comment: @BrianClozel I can find `toBodilessEntity()` but not `releaseBody()`. I'm using `spring-webflux:5.3.8`

Comment: my bad, the `releaseBody` method is only available on the `ClientResponse`, and you can only get it through the now deprecated `exchange()` method.