# ByteBuf leak in netty - still unable to solve

Tags: java, netty

This question is a continuation of this one:

[LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called - how do we solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741540/leak-bytebuf-release-was-not-called-how-do-we-solve-this)

I did everything that was suggested to me there.
I mean:

a) I upgraded netty to version 4.1.52
b) I release now (in my code) all `ByteBuf` instances which I allocate in my code

But still no luck... I keep getting these leak messages/errors from the `ResourceLeakDetector`.

So I again start to seriously think that the problem is within netty itself.

See netty code here

`io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregator.decode(MessageAggregator.java:271)`

It has this code fragment

```
        // A streamed message - initialize the cumulative buffer, and wait for incoming chunks.
        CompositeByteBuf content = ctx.alloc().compositeBuffer(maxCumulationBufferComponents);
        if (m instanceof ByteBufHolder) {
            appendPartialContent(content, ((ByteBufHolder) m).content());
        }
```

Shouldn't this `content`  buffer be released by netty itself?
Who is releasing this buffer? My code has no access to it as it's within netty.

I am posting here the exact leak message I am getting.

Note that in our code/class ConditionalHttpChunkAggregator we do not allocate any **buffer** on that line  118. We just call `super.channelRead(ctx, msg);`   So I think the problem is in that super class code and... even not there but in that `MessageAggregator.java:271` which gets called.

How can this be solved?

```
    (error 1)  
    [2021-03-29T18:39:37,808] [ERROR] io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected.
    Recent access records: 
    Created at:
        io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.compositeDirectBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:223)
        io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.compositeBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:201)
        io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregator.decode(MessageAggregator.java:271)
        io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
        com.yb.jtunnel.protocol.http.decoders.ConditionalHttpChunkAggregator.channelRead(ConditionalHttpChunkAggregator.java:118)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [] 


(error 2)  
2021-03-29T18:39:37,809] [ERROR] io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. 
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.compositeDirectBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:223)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.compositeBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:201)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregator.decode(MessageAggregator.java:271)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) []
```

Comment: In general, when you allocate/create something you also have to deallocate/free it. While there could certainly be a bug in Netty, you might be better off with a hypothesis that you are forgetting something. For a test, you can just deallocate this buffer immediately - if you cannot reproduce this exception, it is very likely that this is the cause.

Comment: @jurez Yes, of course, I know. But that's the thing: I already deallocate all the buffers I allocate. But I cannot deallocate buffers which are allocated  deep down in netty code. I've been chasing this issue for months now (not all the time of course... but it keeps bugging me and coming back to me). I am really really out of ideas what I can do and I am not even sure I can do anything about this (if my theory is correct - that it is a bug in netty).

Comment: You are not supposed to deallocate Netty's internal buffers, but you are (almost certainly) supposed to deallocate yours. If you can prove that this exception occurs even if you don't allocate anything, that would indeed suggest a bug in Netty.

Comment: @jurez Well, yeah, I agree. See the second error which I just posted from `ResourceLeakDetector`. The whole stack trace is within netty, not a single stack trace line of my own code. And it again points to that line `MessageAggregator.java:271` which is within netty.

Comment: The fact that the whole stack trace is within netty doesn't prove that it's a bug in netty.

Comment: @jurez Well, I don't know... I don't claim it's a 100% proof... in any case, I am looking for some suggestions/guidance/ideas how to troubleshoot further. I am out of ideas. Are you familiar with netty code? Did you look in that netty code of MessageAggregator? Who is releasing this buffer? I just don't know how to troubleshoot further. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Netty code, but from what I can see is that it uses some kind of reference counting. When you call `release()`, the count is decreased and when it reaches zero, `deallocate()` should be invoked (probably automatically since it is `protected`). I'm guessing that the code detects that `deallocate()` was not called in time and that throws the exception to prevent memory leaks. Did you make sure that you called `release()`? If you don't do anything with this buffer - just allocate and release it immediately, does the error still happen?

Comment: @jurez OK, your notes are general. I know all this, I've been thinking over this issue for months, and reviewing my app code, and making changes (calling release). Thank you. I need something more specific from somebody who knows `more` about netty than me and you. Thank you anyway.

Comment: No problem - try to raise an issue with Netty developers. However, I see that they there was already a report of the same problem and cause was indeed a missing `release()`. https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2774

Comment: I had similar issue with spring and webflux. When you are tryng to extract request body and you have code like 
InputStream is = new io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream(io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf buffer, boolean releaseOnClose)
You should use releaseOnClose = true 
and do no forget to call:
is.close();
or 
buffer.release()